# Can't read the number of lines in a file using Python

Tags: python, file-handling

I've written a Python code in which I am trying to read the number of lines in the file and it is not executing i.e it is showing some errors.

Code:

```
fhand=open('programms.txt')
count=0
for line in fhand:
    count=count + 1
print('Line Count: ',count)
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/PythonP/files.py", line 3, in <module>
    for line in fhand:
  File "C:\Users\NC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 299: character maps to <undefined>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be an encoding problem, try specifying it when opening the file.

```
fhand=open('programms.txt', encoding="utf8")
count=0
for line in fhand:
    count=count + 1
print('Line Count: ',count)
```

Answer (score 0):

I See that you're facing an error `UnicodeDecodeError` which means that the content of your file contains characters other than [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) You can read the file in other ways, for example if your file is formatted in [utf-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) you'll need an external python module called [codecs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html) to be able to read these characters

```
import codecs

with codecs.open('programms.txt', 'utf-8') as file:
   lines = file.readlines()
   total_lines = len(lines)

print(total_lines)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can get a list containing the lines with `fhand.readlines()`, then get the number of lines with `len()`:

```
fhand = open('programms.txt', "r")
lines = fhand.readlines()
line_count = len(lines)
print("Line Count: ", line_count)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
with open(r"E:\demos\files\read_demo.txt", 'r') as fp:
    for count, line in enumerate(fp):
        pass
print('Total Lines', count + 1)
```